# how does Bitmap work and what canvas really is?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to create a drawing app and found an example from Fingerpaint. I made some modification on the example and was trying to understand how this is accomplished. the example I have is below.

```
public class TestView extends View {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint();

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I understand how `mPaint` is constructed and used. What I don't understand is the code in `onSizeChanged()` and this line `canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);`
. why is there a need to new a `Canvas`? what is the purpose of creating `mBitmap`? why should we draw the Bitmap? why is setting color to `mBitmapPaint` doesn't do anything? Basically I don't understand what `mBitmap`, `mCanvas` and `mBitmapPaint` do. but if I commented those out, the example won't work.

Comment: What's wrong with the official documentation?  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: nothing wrong. the example was taken from android sdk as well. I understand how line is being drawn and how Path is recording the lines. but i dont understand what mBitmap, mCanvas and mBitmapPaint do. they seem to have different behavior that mPath, canvas and mPaint

Comment: okay well the title is a bit confusing then :) but you should still reference the documentation and show that you have indeed understood the basic concepts involved. even better, use the debugger and step through the code to see what is happening.

Comment: I didnt see anything happen when injecting break point and run debug mode untin onDraw is finished. I tried to commend out the 3 objects that I dont understand to see the effect. and also calling setColor on both mPaint and mBitmapPaint. still have no clue what those 3 objects do and why

Comment: I hope my answer helps

Comment: yes, thanks. it does clear some of my questions but i still not completely understand the example

Comment: I'm sorry but this is way too broad and I am deleting my answer. You need to spend some time reading the linked documentation and the docs for View. Otherwise, there is no common vocabulary for interpreting an answer